# In Kotlin, Using Equals & HashCode To Remove Duplicates, How To Choose Which To Remove

Tags: kotlin, duplicates, hashset

I'm using Equals and HashCode to enable HashSet to automatically remove duplicates of my custom class.

When there's a duplicate, how could I define which of the duplicates is removed from the HashSet and which is to remain in the HashSet? I believe the standard behaviour is that the newer object simply isn't added to the HashSet.

Many thanks,
A

Comment: That's not just "standard" behavior but the only available behavior of sets. A set doesn't "remove duplicates", it just refuses the addition of duplicates.

Comment: Ah, OK understood. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to achieve business logic that eliminates duplicates using a custom policy, then use `Map.merge()`.

Comment: I wonder if there's something similar for lists instead of maps?

Comment: No, lists don't consider the equality of items at all. Each item is uniquely identified by its index. It is also computationally inefficient to deduplicate a list. It's an O(n^2) problem.

Comment: Got it, cheers.